# Access data insertion into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm stuck inserting data from an Access table into SQL Server 2008.

I am doing following using C#:

1. Connect to Access database using `OleDbConnection`
2. Execute this statement using `OleDbCommand`:

   ```
   Insert Into Table1
   In Server=localhost;Database=TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI
   Select * From Tables1
   ```

I'm getting the error

> Syntax error in Insert Command

What do I need to do? Please guide.

Comment: I've clarified, I think, what you mean. If you're _not_ inserting from access to SQL-Server please re-edit the question to change these the other way around.

Comment: Hi Marc, My Ultimate target is to insert access table record to SQL Server  table . Please note both table have common structure.

Answer (score 2):

You need something on the lines of:

```
Insert Into
[ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;Server=localhost;Database=TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI].Table1
Select * From Table1
```

The easiest way to get the correct connection string is to link the table and then check the connect property.

You will also find connections strings at http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: 8.5 years is a long time for someone to say … thank you.